# Why is Django giving Page not found error?

Tags: django, cassandra, django-rest-framework

I am Building a Sample REST API using Django-REST-Framework and Apache Cassandra.
Here's my model:

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model


class User(Model):
    read_repair_chance = 0.05
    user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = columns.Text(required=True)
    password = columns.Text(required=True)
    email = columns.Text(required=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get(self,request, format=None):
        uname = [user.name for user in User.object.all()]
        return Response(uname)
```

I am able to add new users and get a list of them.

But when I try to issue a `DELETE` request using `POSTMAN`,

```
DELETE http://localhost:8000/users/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce
```

I am getting page not found 404 error.
Can someone identify where am I going wrong.
Here's the contents of the rest of the files:
**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class UserView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get_user_list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(user.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**Project URLS:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('userdatabase.urls')),
    #path('',)
]

from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UserView
user_list = UserView.as_view({'get':'get_user_list', 'delete': 'delete'})

urlpatterns = [
    path('', user_list, name='user_list'),
    path('users/delete/<uuid:pk>', user_list, name='user_list')
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
import uuid
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4())
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('email', instance.username)
        instance.password = validated_data.get('content', instance.password)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('created', instance.email)
        return instance
```

**EDIT**
When I use `DELETE` on `POSTMAN`, I get this `HTML` response:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Page not found at /users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
        <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; color:#000; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    table { border:none; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
    td, th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ol { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info ol li { font-family: monospace; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="summary">
            <h1>Page not found 
                <span>(404)</span>
            </h1>
            <table class="meta">
                <tr>
                    <th>Request Method:</th>
                    <td>DELETE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Request URL:</th>
                    <td>http://localhost:8000/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>
      Using the URLconf defined in 
                <code>usermanager.urls</code>,
      Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
            </p>
            <ol>
                <li>

                users/



                [name='user_list']

          </li>
                <li>

                users/


                users/delete/&lt;uuid:pk&gt;
                [name='user_list']
```

**Changes with the Updated URL (.../users/users/...)**
[image: Preview tab of the updated response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`http://localhost:8000/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce` instead of
 `http://localhost:8000/users/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce`
I also read your comments, On the basis of, the `404` error raising due to **Two reasons**(or more)
1. The input URL didn't match with any of the defined URLs
2. The User is not found in DB corresponding to the `UUID` given
So, What I suggest is, add a `print()` function inside your `delete()` method to check whether it is called or not during API access.

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    print("inside delete")
    user = self.get_object(pk)
    user.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Or, you can check the response by using `POSTMAN` or something similar tools
If you got any error, please do update your question with traceback and let me know

## Major Update

For deletion API, you should use

```
http://localhost:8000/users/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce
```

That is , we all missed a **`/users`** in the api

## Update-2

change 
`path('users/delete/<uuid:pk>', user_list, name='user_list')` to

```
path('users/delete/<uuid:user_id>', user_list, name='user_list')
```

This is because, you are provided the lookup field as `pk` but it shoulkd be `user_id`

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of **preview** tab in Postman [as you seen in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRX5J.png)

Comment: Anyway I updated the answer (`Major Update` portion)\

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think you've hit something as the response changed to "QueryException at /users/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce Can't resolve column name: 'pk' Request Method: DELETE" though I don't understand this yet. Updating the question with the preview of the new URL as you asked

Comment: Updated the answer (`Update-2` section)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I successfully executed a DELETE on my User using postman and verified it using dbshell. Could you please point towards an easy to understand resource as I am only starting and would like to perfect this.

Comment: I think the [official DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is pretty simple. Also, StackOverflow has the biggest resource with various problem

Answer (score 2):

You have `delete` as part of the URL pattern:

```
path('users/delete/<uuid:pk>', user_list, name='user_list')
```

And yet when you ran postman you used a URL without `delete`:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce
```

You should try this URL instead:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/delete/0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce
```

Comment: I thought specifying the method in the dropdown would be sufficient. I tried with the edited URL but I am still getting the same response.

Comment: The other source of a 404 error would be that there isn't actually a user with pk `0f7b0ada-01ab-4907-b9d2-3fa0d27ae1ce`. Have you double-checked that?

Comment: Yeah its there. Checked it using "python3 manage.py dbshell". Personally I think there's some method missing in one of the files since I am using cassandra and django_cassandra_engine and because of that I have to write most of the stuff manually.